# Playing Youtube DASH Url in Exo Player

Tags: android, exoplayer, youtubeplayer

We are building an android app to play youtube videos in exo player. We generate a DASH URL and play it using exo player

I have following concerns

1. Is it allowed by play store to play youtube URLs without using Youtube player e.g, using Exo player
2. If it is not allowed, What is the way to get it done? Is it allowed if we use the youtube player?
3. Is Youtube player build on top exo player?

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is: No.**

You can play anything to which you have a direct URL to the media. YouTube don't expose direct URLs, so you'd have to use their [player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) instead. Of course, you could host DASH content yourself, as you're doing for HLS, which would provide you with the direct URLs you need.

Comment: So I can us DASH URL and play the videos using exo player and there will not be any issue while publishing apk on playstore. Is this correct?